# html horizontal elements became vertical after adding a <a> tag around it. how to stop that

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added `<a href=>` around the font awesome icons (facebook, twitter) and it made them stack vertically. I have tried all sorts of things, like making sure the display is inline and messing with widths to no avail. If anyone can help me that would be really nice.

It only appears for the media query that is for desktop. So make usre hte screen is large enough. Also, while I am at it...how to turn off the navbar collapse?

http://jsfiddle.net/y5mav/

```
<a href=""><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
<a href=""><li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
```

Is the html in question.

Comment: Your HTML structure for the second list is invalid. An anchor should be enclosed by a list element, not the opposite.

Comment: Wrapping `<a>` tags around `<li>` tags like that is _invalid_ HTML.  The only allowed direct descendants of list (`<ul>` and `<ol>`) tags are `<li>`.

Comment: try display:inline-table or if that dosen't work there is float

Comment: agh. thnak you guys = ) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the link inside of the `<li>`like this:

```
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

you will still need to use the `display: inline-block` to get it to display horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Having `<a>` tags outside `<li>` tags is invalid html.

Use this instead:

```
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
```